# If the List is Empty in the RecyclerView, I want to Display Toast with Empty Message

Tags: java, android, pagination, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I'm getting the default card in `recyclerView` for the concept of pagination,
as my code in the Fragment is as follows:

```
private void onResponse(String response) {


   NewEnquiryPagination newEnquiries = new Gson().fromJson(response, new TypeToken<NewEnquiryPagination>() {
    }.getType());

    Log.i("@sandy,", "newEnquiriesFirstPage: " + newEnquiries);

    if (listOfEnquiries !=null) {

        adapter.addAll(newEnquiries.getContent());

        if (currentPage <= TOTAL_PAGES) adapter.addLoadingFooter();
        else isLastPage = true;
    }
}



private void onResponseNextPage(String response) {

    adapter.removeLoadingFooter();
    isLoading = false;
    NewEnquiryPagination newEnquiries = new Gson().fromJson(response, new TypeToken<NewEnquiryPagination>() {
    }.getType());
    if (listOfEnquiries != null ) {

        adapter.addAll(newEnquiries.getContent());

        if (currentPage != TOTAL_PAGES) adapter.addLoadingFooter();
        else isLastPage = true;
    }
}
```

I'm getting the list from the content as empty but in default i'm getting the card set and also on `SwipeRefresh` the card is increasing by one.... the problem is in `loadFirstPage();` method, if the list is empty i just want to display the `snackbar` as empty and on `SwipeRefresh` i just want to refresh the list.

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Put this If Condition to check the Null and Size of the list,

```
 if (newEnquiries.getContent() != null && newEnquiries.getContent().size() > 0) {
        Log.i("@sss","OnRes");
        adapter.addAll(newEnquiries.getContent());
        if (currentPage <= TOTAL_PAGES) adapter.addLoadingFooter();
        else isLastPage = true;
    } else {
      //Your else condition
    }
```

Hope so it helps